# Django rest framework ListApiView slow query

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a displays table with 147 rows. I am not doing any heavy computation on this data set I just need to get it fast from the database. For now, the load time is 3-4 seconds. Other data comes really fast, why? Does the `ListApiView` work slow?

```
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
class DisplaysList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Displays.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DisplaySerializer
```

```
class Displays(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

class GeoLocation(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32,
                          default=generate_uuid)
    display = models.ForeignKey(
        Displays, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 30, decimal_places=20, blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 30, decimal_places=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

I think the issue is here, how to get efficiently geolocation?

```
class DisplaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    geolocation = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_geolocation(self, obj):
        gl = GeoLocation.objects.filter(display = obj)
        gll = list(gl.values)
        return gll

    class Meta:
        model = Displays
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Please show your model and serializer

Comment: try this: `list(GeoLocation.objects.select_related().filter(display=obj).values())`

Comment: @Ahtisham still slow,  6 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested serializer so that you don't have to return the nested data via a method

```
class GeoLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = GeoLocation
        fields = "__all__"


class DisplaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    geolocation_set = GeoLocationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Displays
        fields = ["name", "owner", "geolocation_set"]
```

Then in your view, use `prefetch_related` to get the nested data in a single query. This will reduce your queries to only two

```
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
class DisplaysList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Displays.objects.all().prefetch_related("geolocation_set")
    serializer_class = serializers.DisplaySerializer
```

Comment: @Iain Shelvington Can he not use `select_related` here ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I'm not sure where you would use `select_related` here. We are using `prefetch_related` to fetch the objects from a reverse relationship but there are no foreign keys relationships to use `select_related` on?

Comment: are you saying when we fetch relation in reverse order it becomes the case of many to one ? case display is foreign key defined.